# Running command in new bash shell with --rcfile and -c

Tags: bash

I'm running the following command and would expect that it would return me `BAR`, as the new shell I create will run .mybashrc first, where it sets `$FOO` before `echo $FOO` will execute.

```
bash --rcfile .mybashrc -c 'echo $FOO'
```

**.mybashrc:**

```
export FOO="BAR"
```

However the result is empty.
What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default, non-interactive `bash` executions do not load initialization files, such as `.bashrc` or the target of your `--rcfile` option.  As described in the `man` page:

```
An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments and without
the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected to terminals
... or one started with the -i option.
```

So you can get the behavior you want by forcing `bash` to act like an interactive shell with `-i`:

```
bash --rcfile .mybashrc -ci 'echo $FOO'
```

Comment: This works, but apparently not when started from an init script (on a cloud VM). In that case it gives the error "no job control in this shell", maybe because there's no TTY. Is there a way to use an rcfile without the shell being interactive?

Comment: @z0r Non-interactive, non-login `bash` shells should execute the contents of the file specified in `$BASH_ENV`.

Comment: Cool, that works. One thing to be aware of when using `BASH_ENV`: if you start sub-shells like `BASH_ENV=./testrc bash -c './test.sh'` then the rcfile will execute twice, unless it unsets `BASH_ENV`.

Comment: @z0r You probably have a shebang (`#!`) at the beginning of `test.sh`, meaning your command as written is invoking bash twice, and thus testrc gets sourced twice.  You should change your command to either `BASH_ENV=./testrc bash ./test.sh` or `BASH_ENV=./testrc ./test.sh`.

Comment: You're right, but (outside this test) I don't control the rc file. I'm worried that it might spawn a sub-shell itself, which would result in infinite recursion. My current solution is to have a wrapper rc file that unsets `BASH_ENV` at the start and then sources the target, which is specified by another environment variable.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  It would be pretty weird for an `rc` file to spawn a shell, but if you're trying to account for all the malicious possibilities, then I agree with your approach.

Comment: this is awesome, it allows to create an overridden definition of `watch`, able to handle functions and aliases at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

Running an interactive `bash -i` is not a good solution, it's declaring a terminal TTY when maybe (probably) there's no terminal, as most people want a their `bash -c` command to run batch processed, logged and unattended.

My preferred way is to prepend the '.' (dot) command to load a profile into the user environment:

```sh
bash -c '. ~/.mybashrc && echo $FOO'
```